# How to whitelist just some attributes with HTMLpurifier?

Tags: attributes, whitelist, htmlpurifier

How to whitelist just some attributes with HTMLpurifier?
I want HTMLpurifier to delete all the other, not allowed attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML.AllowedAttributes](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.AllowedAttributes). Note that [when using HTML.AllowedAttributes, you need to also be using HTML.AllowedElements](http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,3048,3049#msg-3049). And [you'll probably need to add more as you go along](http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,2928,2929#msg-2929). Like `AllowedFrameTargets` for `target=""`, `AllowedRel`, `AllowedRev`, `EnableAttrID`, ... Not much choice but testing thoroughly.

Comment: Thats the option, but how can I check, if it isn't overwritten by anything?